# How to output a parameter in a form application in C#?

Tags: c#, forms, parameters, arguments

I am trying to run one application (a compiled/ built C# form program) while passing a parameter to it with:

```
Process process = Process.Start(@"[insertDirectory]", "HelloWorld");
```

In the parenthesis to the entry point/ main method:

-A command line application has:

```
string[] args
```

A form has:

```
object sender, EventArgs e
```

To my surprise, I cannot use `EventArgs e` in the same way as `string[] args`.

The parameter can be outputted in a console application with `args[0]`. How can I do the same in a form application?

**Correction**

```
object sender, EventArgs e
```

Is in the _load parenthesis. That method is NOT the entry point. Refer to John's/ top answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The entry point to your Program is still `Main()` in `Program.cs`. You can simply add `string[] args`:

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string [] args)
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}
```

And then you can potentially** replace `new Form1()` with `new Form1(args)` and then update your form constructor:

```
public Form1(string [] args)
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

**  The implementation details once you have the arguments are really up to you. You can inject the arguments into your form any number of ways.

Comment: Also note that OnLoad method is not the method that "starts" the program, but rather an event which is called when the form loads. so it does not have nothing to do with passing parameters on start.

Comment: @itay_421 Indeed.

Comment: Is the top code referring to the console application? I copy and pasted it into the form code and an error said "Program has more than one entry point defined. Compile with /main to specify the type that contains the entry point."

Comment: Rahul, look at Program.cs. Your Form is _not_ the entry point to your application.

Comment: I now understand what you meant. Future visitors: On the right hand side of Visual Studio where you have all your items (forms, classes, etc.) listed, there is a Program.cs file. Open that and add "string[] args" in the Main parenthesis. And then add "args" in the parenthesis for your Form. Then add "string[] args" inside the parenthesis for the public method which contains "InitializeComponent()". Viola!

Comment: @itay "it does not have nothing" I think you meant "it does not have anything".